# Delphi TWebBrowser as HTML Editor - get font properties

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-7, twebbrowser

I am using TWebBrowser as HTML editor in Delphi7, by setting it's designMode to 'on' in OnDocumentComplete.

I know how to change font properties like bold, italic, font, color, justify, etc. I am using exeCommand with parameters

```
var
  htmlDoc: HTMLDocument;
  parameter: OleVariant;
begin
  (wbEditor.Document as IHTMLDocument2).ParentWindow.Focus;
  htmlDoc := wbEditor.document as HTMLDocument;
  htmlDoc.execCommand('bold', false, parameter);
  (wbEditor.Document as IHTMLDocument2).ParentWindow.Focus;
end;
```

Question is how to read 'Bold' and other properties when I change cursor position inside the text.

Let's asume my text is like '**foo** bar'. I want to have a 'Bold button' checked when I position my cursor at FOO, but unchecked when I position it at BAR.

???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hej I found a walkaround on my own, used TEmbeddedWB instead TWebBrowser, and code below on it's OnClock and OnKeyDown events

```
var
  doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  sel: IHTMLSelectionObject;
  range: IHTMLTxtRange;
begin
  doc := wb1.Doc2;
  if Assigned(Doc) then
  begin
    Sel := Doc.selection;
    if Assigned(Sel) then
    begin
      if (Sel.type_ = 'None') or (Sel.type_ = 'Text') then
      begin
        Range := Sel.createRange as IHTMLTxtRange;

        Caption := Range.queryCommandValue('justifyCenter');
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

thanks myself !!